# XGBoost feature importance: How do I get original variable names after encoding

Tags: python, encoding, xgboost

I am using XGBoost classification following the guide from a DataCamp course. The data was treated as follows:

```
X, y = df.iloc[:,:-1], df.iloc[:,-1]

# Create a boolean mask for categorical columns: check if df.dtypes == object
categorical_mask = (X.dtypes == object)

# Get list of categorical column names
categorical_columns = X.columns[categorical_mask].tolist()

# Create LabelEncoder object: le
le = LabelEncoder()

# Apply LabelEncoder to categorical columns
X[categorical_columns] = X[categorical_columns].apply(lambda x: le.fit_transform(x))

# Create OneHotEncoder: ohe
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=categorical_mask, sparse=False)

# Apply OneHotEncoder to categorical columns - output is no longer a dataframe: df_encoded is a NumPy array
X_encoded = ohe.fit_transform(X)

testy = pd.DataFrame(X_encoded)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(testy, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

DM_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = y_train, )
DM_test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label = y_test)
```

I tuned the hyperparameters with cross-validated grid search and I fit the models with the `x_train` and `y_train`.

I fit the model with the tuned parameters and then created the Feature Importance Plot:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

xgb.plot_importance(model, importance_type = 'gain')
```

This is the output:

[image: Feature Importance Plot]

How do I map these features back to the original data? I am confused because I used both `LabelEncoder()` and `OneHotEncoder()`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used DictVectorizer instead and it fixed the problem:

```
X, y = df.iloc[:,:-1], df.iloc[:,-1]

# Import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

# Convert df into a dictionary using .to_dict(): df_dict
df_dict = X.to_dict("records")

# Create the DictVectorizer object: dv
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

# Apply dv on df_dict: df_encoded
X_encoded = dv.fit_transform(df_dict)

X_encoded = pd.DataFrame(X_encoded)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)
```

Now fit the model and plot the feature importances:

[image: Feature Importance Plot]

Finally, you have to look up the names:

```
# Use pprint to make the vocabulary easier to read
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dv.vocabulary_)
```

If anyone knows how to get the plot to use the dictionary vocabulary to look up the feature names and put them on the plot, I would greatly appreciate your input.